# Updating TextView from Async Task which use custom program dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

In one of my app, I have a scenario where I need to do some background task. For doing that I am using Async Task. Also I am using custom progress dialog. Below is the layout of the custom progress dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progressloader" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/progressMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Please wait...." />

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything works fine but when I try to set text to TextView then I am getting java NullPointerException.

AsyncTask code

```
private class InitialSetup extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent(),R.style.progressdialog);


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);

        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
                    //    txtView.setText("Testing");    here I am getting the error
            fetchDetails();

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }

            populateUI(getApplicationContext());
        }
    }
```

MainActivity

```
public class SummaryActivity extends Activity {


final TextView txtView = (TextView)findbyid(R.id.progressMessage);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.accountsummary);

              new InitialSetup().execute("");

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the code of your Asynctask? Also it would helpful to add the line where to NullPointerException occurs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your `TextView` of which you want to set the text can be found in the xml file progressbar.xml (i.e. `R.layout.progressbar`). This `TextView` can be obtained once the content view has been set (using `setContentView()`). In your code you set it before this call is been and the code of mussharapp, he is calling it to early. Namely, he calls it after the `setContentView(R.layout.accountsummary)` call which does not contain the `TextView`. Consequently, the variable `txtView` will be NULL and you will get a `NullPointerException`.

What you should do is the following:

- Set the variable txtView in `onPreExecute`, after `setContentView` is called.
- Based on Paresh Mayani's [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10196528/1327789): Use the runOnUiThread method.

For the code look down below:

```
private class InitialSetup extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent(),R.style.progressdialog);
        // The variable is moved here, we only need it here while displaying the
        // progress dialog.
        TextView txtView;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
            // Set the variable txtView here, after setContentView on the dialog
            // has been called! use dialog.findViewById().
            txtView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressMessage); 
        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // Already suggested by Paresh Mayani:
            // Use the runOnUiThread method.
            // See his explanation.
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                  txtView.setText("Testing");       
               }
            });

            fetchDetails();
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }

            populateUI(getApplicationContext());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes, because you are trying to set the TextView inside the doInBackground() method, and this is not allowed,

Why not allowed? Because There is a only one Thread running which is UI Main Thread, and it doesn't allowed to update UI from thread process. read more info here: [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

So there is a solution if you want to set the TextView inside the doInBackground() method, do the UI updating operations inside the [**runOnUiThread**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.

**Otherwise,** suggestion is to do all the UI display/update related operations inside the onPostExecute() method instead of doInBackground() method of your AsyncTask class.

Answer (score 1):

```
(TextView)findViewByid(R.id.progressMessage);
```

should only be executed after the command setContentView().

```
TextView txtView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accountsummary);
    **txtView = (TextView)findbyid(R.id.progressMessage);**


    new InitialSetup().execute("");

}
```

Also you can only change UI elements in the main UI thread. doInBackground() is not in the main UI thread. Make UI changes in onPostExecute

```
public class InitialSetup extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

        private Activity activity;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public InitialSetup(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }




        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Starting task....");
            progressDialog.show();    
        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // do something

            //        

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
             //Perform all UI changes here
            **textView.setText("Text#2");**
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried but I am still getting the error. Also TextView which I am trying to update is part of Custom progress dialog layout

Answer (score 1):

The explanations are correct: You are not to make UI changes in any thread except the thread which create the UI. But AsyncTask has a method called

```
onProgressUpdate()
```

which always will run in the UI Thread. So based on the modifications by dennisg your code should look like this:

```
private class InitialSetup extends AsyncTask<String, String, Long> {

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent(),R.style.progressdialog);
    // The variable is moved here, we only need it here while displaying the
    // progress dialog.
    TextView txtView;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressbar);
        // Set the variable txtView here, after setContentView on the dialog
        // has been called! use dialog.findViewById().
        txtView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressMessage); 
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
        publishProgress("Testing");

        fetchDetails();

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }

        populateUI(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... update) {
        if (update.length > 0)
            txtView.setText(update[0]); 
    }
}
```

Note that the type of the parameter of onProgressUpdate is the second type given in AsyncTask!

**Extra:** To make your code more robust you should check if the progress dialog still exists before setting the text.