# TextView doesn't append after executing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, textview

You can see that I'm appending tvStatus (TextView) in onPostExecute and after remove my progressDialog box. When I debug my code I can see that the value is set in tvStatus but it doesn't show on the screen.

Also my progressDialog stops rotating after the onPostExecute function is called.
Does any one know why and how to solve?

This is set in the onCreate method:

```
tvStatus = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
```

Code:

```
public class TcpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            //set up a Connection
            Socket s = new Socket("88.26.249.133", TCP_SERVER_PORT);
            InputStream inputstream = (s.getInputStream());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inputstream);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            s.setSoTimeout(20*1000);
            //prepare output message
            outBuffer[0] = 48;
            outBuffer[1] = 51;
            outBuffer[2] = 49;
            outBuffer[3] = 49;
            outBuffer[4] = 0;
            outBuffer[5] = 0;
            //send output message
            out.write(outBuffer);
            out.flush();
            //To check in logCat
            Log.i("TcpTask", "sent: " + outBuffer);
            //check # available data
            //and use it as byte length
            avail = in.available();
            byte[] inBuffer = new byte[avail];
            //accept server response
            while ((nob = in.read(inBuffer)) != -1) {
            }
            //close stream
            in.close();
            for (int i = 7; i < avail-7; i += 2) {
                lowByte = inBuffer[i];
                highByte = inBuffer[i+1];
                if (lowByte < 0) {
                    result = lowByte + 256 + (highByte * 256);
                } else {
                    result = lowByte + (highByte * 256);
                }
            }
            //close connection
            s.close();
            //To Check in logCat
            Log.i("TcpTask", "received: " + inBuffer);
            // if the host name could not be resolved into an IP address.   
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("myStatus", "TcpClient: Host name could not be resolved");
            // if an error occurs while creating the socket.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("myStatus", "TcpClient: ERROR");
        } finally {
            Log.i("TcpTask", "TCPClient: Finished");
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        tvStatus.append(Integer.toString(result) + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        if (myStatus.this.progDialog != null) {
            myStatus.this.progDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tvStatus.setText(tvStatus.getText().toString+(Integer.toString(result) + System.getProperty("line.separator")));
```

This is how you set the Text value to the textView

Comment: Yeah, but what append() is then for?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: `Convenience method: Append the specified text to the TextView's display buffer, upgrading it to BufferType.EDITABLE if it was not already editable.` as per the documentation. it appends to the BUFFER. not to the Text which is displayed

Comment: Yeah, but what it is for? Regardless of wherever it appends

Comment: I've always used append() and it worked fine. And also tried setText several times (also tried your method) but it keeps setting the value in the corresponding TextView but nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: in your "LogCat" write the value of "result".

Comment: difference between setText() and append is that the first destroy the buffer content and the buffer will be filled by the tet to set and the second it add to the buffer onother text and print the result

Comment: for exemple if you have tv.setText("Hello"); you will get Hello on the screen and if that instruction you add tv.append ("EveryBody");
you will get HelloEverybody on the screen

Comment: result is a temperature value like 2667 (=26,67). And this is ok, the problem is not in the value but the fact that it's not appearing on the screen.

Comment: is your "tvStatus" a single line TextView?

Comment: No, I've used this before without the AsyncTask and progressDialog and it worked. But I had some other probs that's why I use AsyncTask now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10196709/1320263 this is how you update the textview in Async Task.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
tsStatus.setText(result+" "+ System.getProperty("line.separator");
```