# Update TextView for different fragments from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask

I was looking over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194931/updating-textview-from-async-task-which-use-custom-program-dialog) and it seemed to only deal with a single textview.

Basically, I have an Android application with `n` fragments, each of which has a textview that is populated from a remote call to a database.  Each time the fragment is selected, that remote call will fire and the textview should be repopulated.

Currently, I am using a central AsyncTask to accomplish this, however I am starting to wonder if it is the correct way to go about doing so (some textviews take too long to update for small amounts of data, some don't get updated at all, etc.).

Here is the code from my `RetrieveData` class.  Essentially, it figures out which textview is to be updated, and then populates that textview.

```
public class RetrieveData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
  private int txtViewID = -1;
  private Activity mainActivity;

  public RetrieveData(Activity a) { mainActivity = a; }

  protected String[] doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String[] data;

    // call web script to return JSON data
    ...

    // figure out which fragment called which script
    if (urls[0] == "get_A.php") {
      data = parseJSONdata();    // parse out the JSON
      txtViewID = R.id.txtViewA; // find INT-based ID
    } else if (urls[0] == "get_B.php") {
      data = parseOtherJSONdata();  // different type of call
      txtViewID = R.id.txtViewB;
    } else ... {
      ...
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
  }

  return data;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] op) {
  if (txtViewID != -1) { // call was made
    TextView tv = (TextView)mainActivity.findViewById(txtViewID);
    tv.setText(op[0]);
}
```

and here is how I call this from a Fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    Activity mainActivity;

    public MainFragment(Activity a) { mainActivity = a; }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_tab,container,false);
        new RetrieveData(mainActivity).execute("get_A.php","1");
        return v;
    }
}
```

To me, its very kludgy and probably belies my newness to Android, so any suggestions for improvement are heartily appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a couple of things to improve the robustness and performance and fix some issues which will creep in later:

1. Don't use `findViewById()` outside of init/setup type methods.  It is an expensive call as it has to "search" your hierarchy for the ID you are requesting.
2. Don't use an overloaded constructor for your `Fragment` which takes the `Activity`.  The `Fragment` default constructor should be empty.  This allows the system to properly re-create your `Fragment` when configuration changes (screen rotates.)  The `Fragment` will receive its attached `Activity` at the correct time when its `onAttach()` method is called, so there is no need to do this.
3. You shouldn't need the `Activity` at all for what you're trying to do.  Instead, have your `Fragment` get the correct `TextView` from your layout in its `onCreateView()`.  What you do from there is really up to you:

   - Pass the `TextView` instance to your `RetrieveData` class constructor as the one to be updated.  This eliminates the hard coded IDs in your `RetrieveData` class, which gets rid of some explicit coupling and is a better approach.  This is still very tightly coupled, though, since it depends on having a specific `View` so still not a great option IMHO.
   - Have the `RetrieveData` class define an inner `Callback` interface and have the `Fragment` implement it.  The constructor for `RetrieveData` can then take an instance of the `Callback` interface (e.g. your `Fragment` instance) and when its `onPostExecute()` runs it just calls back the `Fragment` with the appropriate data.  Now it is up to your `Fragment` implementation to make the right decision on what UI element it is hosting to update with the data.  It may be a `TextView` now, but in the future you could make it something else, etc.  Now you have decoupled the class from all explicit UI ties and put the responsibility on the thing hosting the UI elements: the `Fragment`.

Here's a brief example of the 2nd bullet:

```
public RetrieveData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
    //  Define the interface used to provide results
    public interface Callback {
        public void onDataLoaded(String[] result);
    }

    private Callback  mCb;

    public RetrieveData(Callback cb) {
        mCb = cb;
    }

    ...
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        mCb.onDataLoaded(result);
    }
}

public MyFragment extends Fragment implements RetrieveData.Callback {
    TextView      mResult;
    RetrieveData  mAsyncRetriever;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_tab,container,false);

        //  Get the TextView now where we want to show results.
        //  This avoids calling findViewById() constantly.
        mResult = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.example_result);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        //  Keep a reference to the AsyncTask so we can properly
        //  cancel it when our lifecycle events dictate so.
        mAsyncRetriever = new RetrieveData(this);
        mAsyncRetriever.execute("get_A.php");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        //  If we have a pending data load going on, kill it.
        if (mAsyncRetriever != null) {
            mAsyncRetriever.cancel(true);
            mAsyncRetriever = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataLoaded(String[] result) {
        //  Only pulling the first result provided
        mResult.setText(result[0]);

        //  The RetrieveData is done, get rid of our ref
        mAsyncRetriever = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the main points for (1), (2), and (3)/(3)a are all related to the fact that I felt I needed to pass that reference to the `Activity` in there.  I can resolve that issue.  So with the inner callback approach, I'm not following.  Is the callback implementing the full AsyncTask, or simply updating the text?

Comment: I'll add a brief example to the answer to help clarify.

Comment: One change.  You need to add a call to `super.onResume()` in the `onResume` function and `super.onPause()` to the `onPause()` function, but otherwise works great.  Thanks!