# How to Set textview in doINBackground android

Tags: java, android, android-runonuithread

I want to access a postgresql database, but I have a problem with `AsyncTask` and `doInBackground` commands. I don't know why I can't update my textview at `onPostExecute`. Can anyone explain me what is the problem? Here is my code:

```
package com.example.armyhealthcare;

import java.sql.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://elmer-02.db.elephantsql.com.5432/xyz";
    private static final String user = "user";
    private static final String pass = "pass";
    private TextView firstname, lastname;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textfname);
        lastname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textlname);
        Button buttonload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonload);

        buttonload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                new mytask().execute();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private class mytask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        private String finame=""; 
        private String laname="";
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){

            try{
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

                    Statement st = con.createStatement();                   
                    final ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from book");
                    rs.next();
                    finame= rs.getString(1);
                    laname= "Show Me";

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            firstname.setText("finame");
            lastname.setText(laname);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get any errors?

Comment: what is your error or what response you getting

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie Why do you think this is a duplicate for that question?

Comment: @MuratK. you know what! its not, I thought he initialized the view before setContentView but he didn't, Also the Answers are not right in this case as it should work as expected the way it is.
Something wrong with the retrieved data probably

Comment: Thanks for your help but its not worked. I found the problem. I cant pass string from inside of "Try". its confused me..

Answer (score 2):

To set text in doInBackground you can use this.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                  txtView.setText("Message");       
               }
            });
```

Try this:

[Updating TextView from Async Task which use custom program dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194931/updating-textview-from-async-task-which-use-custom-program-dialog)

Comment: Thanks for your help but its not worked. I found the problem. I cant pass string from inside of "Try". its confused me..

Comment: This answer is plain wrong and should have not received any upvotes. Future readers will be mislead. The `onPostExecute` already runs on the UI-Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `runOnUiThead()` or set text in `onPostExexute()`

**Example :**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tvText.setText("ABC");
                        }
                    });
```

**Edited :**
**Good Way :**

```
private class mytask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private String finame="";
        private String laname="";
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){

            try{
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                final ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from book");
                rs.next();
                finame= rs.getString(1);
                laname= "Show Me";
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            firstname.setText(finame);
            lastname.setText(laname);
        }

    }
```

**Bad Way :**

```
private class mytask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private String finame="";
        private String laname="";
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){

            try{
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                final ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from book");
                rs.next();
                finame= rs.getString(1);
                laname= "Show Me";

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        firstname.setText(finame);
                        lastname.setText(laname);
                    }
                });

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

set first name and last name like this

Comment: Thanks for your help but its not worked. I found the problem. I cant pass string from inside of "Try". its confused me..

Comment: what you want to set in textview ? first name and last name of your code ?

Comment: I want to set firstname and lastname textviews with "finame" and "laname" which are at "try" command. But its not working..

Comment: There is no error. I can run application successfully but the problem is that I can't set string which comes from "try" command  to the textview.

Comment: Debug your code and check your control goes to doInBackgroud() ?

Comment: Yes it goes. Can you please run this code on your local machine? Maybe you can solve my problem. Thanks for your help..

Comment: check your variable finame and laname contain values in debug mode ? Then also check when setText() method set.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the result or object from `String doInBackground()` to `onPostExecute(String result)`

Please follow the example.

From the `doInBackground()` method:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0){

         //Your code here
         return rs.getString(1);;
}
```

From the `onPostExecute()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
     super.onPostExecute(result);
     firstname.setText(result);
     lastname.setText("Show Me");

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but its not worked. I found the problem. I cant pass string from inside of "Try". its confused me..