# Retrieving data before executing php file

Tags: php, android

How can you retrieve a textView text in android so the .php file will read it as an ID for '$_id' before pre-executing the php file? Since in my php file I need to retrieve an ID from my android studio before I execute the json array (That's what I think at least in the error I'm getting)

I'm new in programming so please explain it like when you're still a newbie in programming

This is my code for php:

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';
$db='employee101';
$_id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "select * from employee_comments where id = $_id;";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    array_push($response,array("id"=>$row[0],"comment"=>$row[1],"rating"=>$row[2]));

}

echo json_encode(array("server_respo"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);




?>
```

Below is my codes in android studio
    package rjj.tutorial_jsonandlistview;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String Json_STRING;
    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new BackgroundTask().execute();
         //new line


    }




    /*public void getJSON(View view) {

        new BackgroundTask().execute();

    }*/


    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String json_url;
        String JSON_STRING;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            json_url = "http://10.0.2.2/json_comments.php";
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(json_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView.setText(result);
            Json_STRING = result;
        }

    }
```

EDIT:
php file

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';
$db='employee101';

if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
$_id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "select * from employee_comments where id = $_id;";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    array_push($response,array("id"=>$row[0],"comment"=>$row[1],"rating"=>$row[2]));

}
}

echo json_encode(array("server_respo"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);




?>
```

Added a new line in pre-execute to retrieve ID but I think it's not working

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            String password = textView.getText().toString();


            json_url = "http://10.0.2.2/json_comments.php";
        }
```

Error in PHP:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\json_comments.php on line
>   6  Notice: Undefined variable: response in
>   C:\wamp64\www\json_comments.php on line 25  Notice: Undefined
>   variable: con in C:\wamp64\www\json_comments.php on line 27  Warning:
>   mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in
>   C:\wamp64\www\json_comments.php on line 27

Comment: updated my answer again, just replace code with your file

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your code within condition

```
if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
  # place your code here
}
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php 
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';
$db='employee101';

if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
    $_id = $_POST['id'];

    $sql = "select * from employee_comments where id = $_id;";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $response = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        array_push($response,array("id"=>$row[0],"comment"=>$row[1],"rating"=>$row[2]));

    }

echo json_encode(array("server_respo"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);

}
?>
```

Comment: Where should I put that condition, can you please tell me?

Comment: updated answer,keep rest of the line as it is. It will not execute your code until it have `id`

Comment: I'm still having the same error, the undefined variable thingy with id :(

Answer (score 0):

In php file, you get ID from **$_POST['id']**. So that, in Java file, **HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection** you need use method POST, and send data is ID to php file.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String Json_STRING;
    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new BackgroundTask().execute();
        //new line


    }




    /*public void getJSON(View view) {

        new BackgroundTask().execute();

    }*/


    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String json_url;
        String JSON_STRING;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            json_url = "http://10.0.2.2/json_comments.php";
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                String urlParameters  = "id=your_id";
                byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
                int    postDataLength = postData.length;
                String request        = json_url;;
                URL    url            = new URL( request );
                HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput( true );
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
                conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
                conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
                conn.setUseCaches( false );
                try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
                    wr.write( postData );
                }

                if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    is = urlConn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                        stringBuilder.append(inputLine + "\n");
                    in.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString().trim();



                    //Your code read data return here ...

                } else {
                    is = urlConn.getErrorStream();
                }

                return null;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView.setText(result);
            Json_STRING = result;
        }

    }
```

Comment: @RizalJulianBlanco, put it to **protected String doInBackground(Void... params)**, replace your **try - catch** block.

Answer (score -1):

First of all u cannot set value in textview inside asynctask as all the ui related operations can be done only on ui thread see below

- Based on Paresh https://stackoverflow.com/a/10196528/1327789: Use the runOnUiThread method.

And if you want to read and write text in your code u can do following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String Json_STRING;
TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
    String text=textview.getText();
    new BackgroundTask().execute(text);
     //new line


}




/*public void getJSON(View view) {

    new BackgroundTask().execute();

}*/

// change first param of asynctask to String to accept array of string params

class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String json_url;
    String JSON_STRING;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        json_url = "http://10.0.2.2/json_comments.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
String param=params[0]; // you can access text of textview from here and pass it to your url like "json_url?id=param"
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((JSON_STRING = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING + "\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              textView.setText(result);       
           }
        });
    }

}
```

php android

Comment: How do I do the runOnUI thingy, can you please guide me on how I do it, I'm very new in programming

Comment: just use the above code in postExecute as  it will gain excess to android's main UI thread and then can access all the elements present on this thread and all the views lie on this thread.

Comment: I'm having an error in your oncreate textView=findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);
    String text=textview.getText();. It says incompatible types

Comment: String text=textview.getText().toString(); and make sure you set id of textview in xml same as java file

Comment: also Variable 'result' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Comment: just declare a global String variable and assign result value to it so that u can it evry where.

Comment: Should the 'param' in "String param = params[0];" be grayed out? because param is greyed

Comment: bro i have added a comment there to show usage its upto u ,how would u use it but for sure u get value from textview here, hence the solution to problem u asked